# Masking floating point cv::Mat without looping

Tags: c++, opencv

At a point in my code I have a `cv::Mat` with the type `CV_8U` and a `cv::Mat` with the type `CV_64f`. I want to know if there is a clever way to masking the floating point image with the char image without having to loop through the images and do it explicitly.

I realize this isn't a terribly pressing issue to just write, I'm just curious if it is possible to help with readability succinctness in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized I was thinking about the operation the wrong way. Masking the floating point image is the same as an element-wise matrix multiplication of a binary image. An easy way to do this operation is

```
cv::Mat result = floatImg.mul(mask);
```

`cv::Mat.mul()` can be found in the documentation [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#matrix-expressions).